# What is Jirobo's last name?

Tags: naruto

What is Jirobo's last name? I must know because I am creating a Naruto website and including the full list of characters.

Comment: Jirobo? Do you mean Jiraiya???

Comment: Jirobo of the South Gate

Comment: @NamikazeSheena, I'm not sure "of the South Gate" is a last name. I think it's more of a nickname like "Gaara of the Sand" or "Copy Ninja Kakashi".

Comment: Since Jirobo is not a main character, he might not have a full name, or his full name is not disclosed by the author, or Jirobo is already his full name. I have a friend IRL whose name is just Richard.

Comment: "Gaara of the Sand" = Sabaku no Gaara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, the author hasn't given a last name for Jirobo.
(as far as i know)
There are also other characters without a last name.